# Rails nested photo file upload form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class Scene, which has_one Photo, and Photo belongs_to Scene.  I want to create a form that'll update or create Scene and Photo simultaneously - if Scene already exists, it'll update the Photo with scene_id Scene.id, otherwise, it'll make a new Scene and a new Photo, or if there's no new photo, it'll just update the one Scene field in question ("description").

However I don't have the slightest idea how.  I get the feeling it looks nothing like these other forms.

Oh, and the Photo model is set up to use Attachment-fu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Scene Model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo
```

Form

```
<% form_for @scene do |scene_form| %>
  <!-- Fields for scene form -->

  <% scene_form.fields_for :photo do |photo_form| %>
    <!-- fields for photo form -->  
  <% end %>

<%= customer_form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That's great, thanks.  FF icon ?  I don't have RESTful routes set up for this thing, so can I override the form_for so that the action goes to an arbitrary URL?

Comment: idk, you can try it, here is a pretty simple link for attachment-fu and nested form http://www.brandon-harris.com/rails/2009/10/18/nested-model-forms-and-attachment-fu.html